# Перенос объекта из одного класса в другой

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer

Класс из которого берём:

```
class NewPerson(QtWidgets.QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.ui = Ui_newperson()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
            self.setWindowTitle("Создание нового персонажа")
            self.name = ""
            self.text = ""
            self.FaceOfPerson = ""
            self.FacesOfPerson = ""
    # События нажатия на кнопки
            self.ui.image.clicked.connect(self.ChoiceImage)
            self.ui.makeperson.clicked.connect(self.MakeNewPerson)
            self.ui.preview.clicked.connect(self.Preview)
            self.ui.image_2.clicked.connect(self.ChoiceImages)
    # Подключаем текстовые поля
            self.ui.name.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonName)
            self.ui.aboutpersontext.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonAboutText)
    
    
    # ТЕКСТОВОЕ ПОЛЕ "НОВОЕ ИМЯ"
        def NewPersonName(self, name):
            self.name = name
    
    # ТЕКСТОВОЕ ПОЛЕ "НОВОЕ ОПИСАНИЕ"
        def NewPersonAboutText(self):
            self.text = self.ui.aboutpersontext.toPlainText()
```

Надо взять объект `self.text` и вставить его сюда:

```
class DescriptionPersonPreview(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_descriptionperson()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Создание нового персонажа")
        self.ui.scroll.setPixmap(QPixmap())
        self.textaboutpreview = *ВСТАВИТЬ СЮДА*
        self.ui.textabout.setText(self.textaboutpreview)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробуйте, если что не так - публикуйте весь код.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QPalette, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QListWidget
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from newperson_ui import Ui_newperson


class DescriptionPersonPreview(QtWidgets.QWidget):          # <<<=============
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__()

#        self.ui = Ui_descriptionperson()
#        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Создание нового персонажа")
#        self.ui.scroll.setPixmap(QPixmap())
        self.textaboutpreview = text   #*ВСТАВИТЬ СЮДА*
#        self.ui.textabout.setText(self.textaboutpreview)        
        self.textabout = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.textabout.setText(self.textaboutpreview)
        #self.show()


class NewPerson(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_newperson()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Создание нового персонажа")
        self.name = ""
        self.text = ""
        self.FaceOfPerson = ""
        self.FacesOfPerson = ""
# События нажатия на кнопки
        self.ui.image.clicked.connect(self.ChoiceImage)
        self.ui.makeperson.clicked.connect(self.MakeNewPerson)
        self.ui.preview.clicked.connect(self.Preview)
        self.ui.image_2.clicked.connect(self.ChoiceImages)
# Подключаем текстовые поля
        self.ui.name.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonName)
        #aboutpersontext
        #self.ui.aboutpersontext.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonAboutText)
        self.ui.aboutpersontext.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonAboutText)


# ТЕКСТОВОЕ ПОЛЕ "НОВОЕ ИМЯ"
    def NewPersonName(self, name):
        self.name = name

# ТЕКСТОВОЕ ПОЛЕ "НОВОЕ ОПИСАНИЕ"
    def NewPersonAboutText(self):
        self.text = self.ui.aboutpersontext.toPlainText()
        print("def NewPersonAboutText(self):", self.text)


# ФУНКЦИЯ Загрузки изображения
    def ChoiceImage(self):
        self.FaceOfPerson = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Выберите картинку с лицом исторической личности", None, "Image (*.png *.jpg)")[0]

        print(self.FaceOfPerson)

# ФУНКЦИЯ Загрузки изображения фантомов
    def ChoiceImages(self):
        self.FacesOfPerson = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Выберите картинку с лицами фантомов", None, "*.png *.jpg")
        print(self.FacesOfPerson[0][0]) #[1])

# ФУНКЦИЯ Открытия окна Предварительного просмотра
    def Preview(self):
        self.preview = DescriptionPersonPreview(self.text)           # <<<=============
        self.preview.show()

###        
    def MakeNewPerson(self):
        print("def MakeNewPerson(self):")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = NewPerson()
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]